# Changing static reference from a non static field?

Tags: java, string-length

I have a private int array, and  I need to somehow find the length but I cannot do this under the static class.  I have to keep the class static, is there another method I can add to change a.length to something else?

The issue is caused by a.length.

```
private int [] a;

public static IntegerSet union(IntegerSet otherSet, IntegerSet nextSet) {

                for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
                  if (otherSet.isSet(i))
                    nextSet.insertElement(i);
                }

                return nextSet;
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said use

```
public int lenghtOfArray(){
      return this.a.lenght;
}
```

and change your method to

```
public static IntegerSet union(IntegerSet otherSet, IntegerSet nextSet) {
      for(int i=0; i<otherSet.length(); i++) {
           if (otherSet.isSet(i))
                nextSet.insertElement(i);
           }
           return nextSet;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make `a` static also, or pass an instance of your class as an argument to the `union` method and access that instance's `a` field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the field of an object:

```
private int [] a;

public static IntegerSet union(IntegerSet otherSet, IntegerSet nextSet) {
    . . .
    for(int i=0; i<otherSet.a.length; i++) {
        . . .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not referring to `a.length` from a static *class*; you're doing it from a static *method*. A static method can never refer to non-static member variables.

It appears as if you have a bug there. Why would you go against `a.length`? You should inquire about the `a` member of `otherSet` or `nextSet`.